# Can I make conclusions with two independent samples?

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, inference, survey-sampling

Suppose I have a sample (n°1) that is statistically representative of a country A population, that I randomly selected. I want to give a survey to that sample to infer some things about the true population.

I now have another sample (n°2), that is independent of the first sample and is much smaller, that, because of costly reasons, I selected them from only 3 different cities of the country A. If I make a statistical test for my sample (n°2), can I conclude it for the whole population of country A?

For example, from a survey given to sample (n°1), I see that 30% of the population has a parrot at home. I now select a sample (n°2) from only 3 different cities of country A where everyone in the sample has a parrot. From a statistical test applied to sample (n°2) (which have a parrot) I see that half of those people are likely to be depressed.
Since the survey for sample (n°1) says that 30% of the population has a parrot, can I conclude that half of them, i.e, 15% of the people that have a parrot are likely to be depressed?

My question is if the second sample needs to be a sample of the first sample, or if it can be done separately. I hope my example is not confusing. If possible, please provide a reference to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about with sample 2 is multistage sampling, whereby you first select a random sample clusters, and then randomly sample from within these clusters. Exercise 5.1 in [this book chapter](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F0-387-31075-4_5.pdf) goes over estimating variance for this type of sampling. There is some academic literature saying this is bias, but I was taught it has an undergrad, and it is widely used.

As for your example of comparing two different samples I would give a pretty hard NO as to  making that comparison for the main reason that you are assuming that parrots and depression are independent. In real-life survey data, most variables are at least every so slightly dependent. So unless you're dealing with something where you are sure the two variables are independent, I would steer clear of such conclusions.